# Add Source to Highcharts Export CSV

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'd like to add a row at the end of the exported CSV file that contains a string with the source citation for the downloaded data.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [extend Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) and wrap the `getCSV` function, or edit what happens when you click the `Download CSV` menu item.

An example of editing what happens when you click the menu item ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3g03tuv/175/)):

```
menuItems: [{
    textKey: 'downloadCSV',
    onclick: function () {
        var csv = this.getCSV(true);
        csv += '\n"My source 1","My source 2","My source 3"';
        this.fileDownload(
            'data:text/csv,\uFEFF' + encodeURIComponent(csv),
            'csv',
            csv,
            'text/csv'
        );
    }
}]
```

An example of extending Highcharts ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3g03tuv/181/)):

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'getCSV', function (proceed, useLocalDecimalPoint) {
        // Run the original proceed method
        result = proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        result += '\n"My source 1","My source 2","My source 3"';
        return result;
    });
}(Highcharts));
```