# Extending highcharts in Angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm using highcharts in my Angular project and need to do some manipulation on the export CSV functionality.

I've found an thread here in stackoverflow that seems to explain what I require to do:

[Add Source to Highcharts Export CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333362/add-source-to-highcharts-export-csv)

But unfortunately it is implemented using pure javascript and I'm unable to find out how I'm supposed to extend Highcharts inside an Angular component.

This is what I want to know how to implement in Angular:

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'getCSV', function (proceed, useLocalDecimalPoint) {
        // Run the original proceed method
        result = proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        result += '\n"My source 1","My source 2","My source 3"';
        return result;
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

Here's the working example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3g03tuv/181/)

Comment: OK, so far I have been able to extend the getCSV function by calling Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Chart.prototype, 'getCSV', (proceed, useLocalDecimalPoint) => { ... }) in my ngOnInit. Now the problem is that I'm getting an error telling me that this.getDataRows is not a function when I try to click on te Export CSV menu option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also extract the wrap to a standalone function that will take Highcharts as its parameter. Then all you need to do is to import and initialize it with the `Highcharts`.

```js
//customWrap.ts
export default function(Highcharts) {
  const H = Highcharts;
  H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, "getCSV", function(proceed, useLocalDecimalPoint) {
    // Run the original proceed method
    let result = proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    result += '\n"My source 1","My source 2","My source 3"';
    return result;
  });
}
```

```js
//app.component.ts
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HC_exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting'
import HC_exportData from 'highcharts/modules/export-data';
import customWrap from './customWrap';

HC_exporting(Highcharts);
HC_exportData(Highcharts);
customWrap(Highcharts);
...
```

**Live demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-1jommb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally I manage to get the wrap method working for the getCSV function by adding this in my ngOnInit:

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Chart.prototype, 'getCSV', function(proceed, useLocalDecimalPoint) {
      let result = proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
      result += '\nHello world!';
      return result;
    });
```

Beware of two mistakes I made that cost me a couple of hours to find:

1. Initially I pass **Highcharts.chart.prototype** as the first parameter (note the *lower* case in **chart**), this didn't raise any error on the client side, but it wasn't overriding the getCSV function.
2. Make sure **not** to use array notation when defining the function you pass as third parameter, as that will change the scope of **this** and make your proceed.apply call to fail.

This code will fail:

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Chart.prototype, 'getCSV', (proceed, useLocalDecimalPoint) => {
          // This will fail
          let result = proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
          return result;
        });
```